# Android listview adding data to the top, not adding to bottom

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a listview where am using a chat. When I send a new data it adds to the top of the listview. I have tried bottom stack with listview but still, the issue exists. Please check the below code.

```
     <ListView
        android:id="@+id/messageContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="129dp"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:transcriptMode="normal"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="363dp" /> 


  public void getChat() {
    new AsyncTask<String, String, String>() {
       protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            try {
                JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(s);
                chatLst.clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    ChatMessage chatMesage = new ChatMessage();
                    if (!jsonobject.isNull("id")) {
                        chatMesage.setId(jsonobject.getString("id"));
                    }

                    if (!jsonobject.isNull("text")) {
                        chatMesage.setChattext(jsonobject.getString("text"));
                    }
                    if (!jsonobject.isNull("time")) {
                        chatMesage.setChattime(jsonobject.getString("time"));
                    }

                    chatLst.add(chatMesage);
                }
                if (messagesContainer.getAdapter() == null) {
                    adapter = new ChatAdapter(chatLst, OrderAndChat.this, serverOrderCreator);
                    messagesContainer.setAdapter(adapter);
                } else {
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                progressDialog.hide();

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }.execute();
 }
```

Please help to fix the issue.

Comment: Have you tried adding the items to position 0 on the list ? something like   `chatLst.add(0,chatMesage);`

Comment: The `apdater` takes the default sort of your items in your list, if your insert an item in position 0 on your list, it will be visible at the top on your `listView`

Comment: Thanks, pal. It's working. Is there any way to stop scrolling the listview when refreshing? I will call this getChat function for every 30 secs.

Comment: hmm.. maybe try `listView.setScrollContainer(false)`